# Nginx configuration to deny access to private Laravel folders

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4

Every answer or tutorial about nginx configuration on Laravel has something like that:

```
location ~ \.php {
    # fastcgi stuff ...
}
```

If the Laravel framework has a unique entry point (the public `index.php`), wouldn't it be this definition more accurate?

```
location ~ index\.php {
    # fastcgi stuff ...
}
```

In a context where you have your app deployed on a subfolder, the first configuration it's allowing the access on every php private file, even if I have already defined a `deny all` rule over the private folder.

I'm wrong with anything?

There is another way to define a fully deny access over a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want deny access to files in your private folder (e.g. `/private`) add this to your config for virtual host:

Case sensitive

```
location ~ ^/private/(.*)\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Case insensitive:

```
location ~* ^/private/(.*)\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

This returns 403 all requests to `/private/something.php`, `/private/something/something.php` and so on. But requests to `/private/something` will work.

Comment: Great. So, this is the perfect combination: folder `location /private/ { deny all; }` and php files `location ~* ^/private/(.*)\.php$ { deny all; }`